# PhpStorm 2021.3.2 Settings

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, settings

I am new using PhpStorm. Previously I used Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text 3/4, however with PhpStorm it is much more convenient to work with PHP and I am happy with the IDE.

I have customized the style of the code according to my needs and the convention of the Framework I am working with. The problem arises when doing a cleanup and/or reformatting of the code: when this happens, the protected and public methods get mixed up. I will try to explain it as best as possible.

For example: if I have a protected method named `getPath` that is called in one or more public methods at the beginning of the class, by convention this method should be at the end of the class along with the private methods, but then if I set another public method that does not use the `getPath` method, `getPath` is placed on top of the new public method. I KNOW! It doesn't seem to be a problem, but when you follow strict convention rules of a framework or a personal convention, this ends up being very important.

In my case, I'm extremely clean and tidy in my code, but I haven't been able to configure the IDE to keep methods private and protected at the end of the class.

I would like to know if someone can help me configure the IDE to solve the problem and if possible I would like the magic methods (`__call`, `__callStatic`, `__sleep`, `__get`) to be kept at the end of everything.

I am using PhpStorm 2021.3.2.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#arrange_code -- Rearrange code -- all setting that the IDE can use are there. I assume you are using it already?..

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't noticed that part in the settings. I haven't tried it but I guess it should work.

Comment: The IDE is complex to configure in my opinion. At first I didn't fully understand the settings because it's so loaded with options that it ends up being a bit confusing. In the Arrangement section, I only adjusted it to the standard of the Framework I'm using, but I didn't pay much attention to the rest.